# How could Jake knock runabout's window in "Facets" episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I completely don't get the opening scene of "[Facets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Facets_(episode))" episode.

How could Jake stand (?) outside a runabout and knock its window, even if it was just a holosuite simulation? What kind of space flight simulation is that, if someone can "walk into" space you're flying through? How can the computer simulate space, through which a runabout is flying, if it was simulating solid ground, on which Jake was walking, at the same time?

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good in-universe answer for this, although I'm pondering it. The truth is that holosuites are the area where Star Trek writers are most guilty of falling back on magic and expediency. Holodecks and holosuites, by and large, do exactly what the script needs them to, and are limited only by what a given script needs them to be limited by, and obey no sane rules.

Comment: Technically speaking, only the sensors and main view-screen need to simulate space flight. The holodeck may have just simulated a 'real' simulator on the walls surrounding it displaying space objects, like the flight simulators we have now. In other words - Jake may have just walked up to a mock up of the runabout on a gimbal.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell That was sort of the in-universe answer I was groping toward, so I'd say go ahead and make that the answer and not just a comment.

Comment: “ What kind of space flight simulation is that, if someone can "walk into" space you're flying through?” — Are you saying the holodeck should have suffocated and frozen Jake, whilst bombarding his body with radiation?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You have to admit that would be a more valid simulation :-) Might violate safety protocols tho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically speaking, only the sensors and main view-screen need to simulate space flight. The holodeck may have just simulated a 'real' simulator, while on the walls surrounding it space objects are displayed - like the flight simulators we have now. In other words - Jake may have just walked up to a mock up of the runabout on a gimbal

Comment: That was my reading as well. He presumably asked it to create him a simulator and that's precisely what it did.